# cast a class to an activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to create a listView which enables me to open 2 other activities I created before. I've got a problem with my intent. I'm quite sure it does understand that Lactivity is an activity which already exists. Could you explain to me why?

```
public ListMenu extends Activity {

private ListView malistView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    // create list of elements
    List<ElementOfConstruction> liste = new ArrayList<ElementOfConstruction>();

    String Columns = null;
    Class<?> CalculColumns = null;
    ElementOfConstruction columns = new ElementOfConstruction(Columns, 0, R.drawable.columns, CalculColumns, 100);
    liste.add(columns);
    String Beam1 = null;
    Class<?> CalculBeam = null;
    ElementOfConstruction beam1 = new ElementOfConstruction(Beam1, 0, R.drawable.beam1, CalculBeam, 200);

    //Récupération de la listview créée dans le fichier main.xml  
    malistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.malistview);

    ArrayAdapter<ElementOfConstruction> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ElementOfConstruction>(ListMenu.this,
            R.layout.row_list, R.id.name, liste);

    // Affecter l'Adapter à notre ListView
    malistView.setAdapter(adapter);

    malistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            //On récupère le titre de l'Item dans un ElementOfConstruction


            //start new activity
            //récupération de l’item sélectionné
            ElementOfConstruction element = (ElementOfConstruction)malistView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

            Class<?> Lactivity = element.getActivity();
            int numIdentification = element.getNumIdentification();

            //open a new activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListMenu.this, Lactivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,numIdentification);
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Please provide logcat

Comment: You need to post the stacktrace/logcat error that is occuring.  Is it happening when it compiles or runtime?

Comment: What is the ElementOfConstruction type and what returns element.getActivity() returns exactly ? And mor important, is there an error somewhere ? what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: I have a problem with, `Intent intent = new Intent(ListMenu.this, Lactivity.class);` Eclipse indicates "Lactivity cannot be resolved to a type"

My problem is basically to say that Lactivity is an Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the class of your Activity to the Intent, not the Activity itself.

Change this line:

```
Class<?> Lactivity = element.getActivity();
```

To:

```
Activity Lactivity = element.getActivity();
```

Comment: the problem is that "elment" is an object of ElementofConstruction which is basicly: 
`public class ElementOfConstruction {
  private String name;
  private int numBag;
  private int icone ;
  private int numIdentification;
  private Class<?> anActivity;`

I tried to write `private Activity anActivity` but Eclipse tells me "Activity cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: `private Activity anActivity` is definitely the way to go. You have to import Activity from android.app.Activity.

Comment: I had then to write  `Lactivity.getClass()` instead of `Lactivity.class` in my intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
`malistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
       switch(position)
       {
          case 0:
             intentActivity = Lactivity.class
             break;
          case 1:
             intentActivity = Otheractivity.class
             break;
       }


        //open a new activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(ListMenu.this, Lactivity);
        startActivityForResult(intent,numIdentification);



    }
});`
```